# Seam Component.getInstance() and unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, inversion-of-control, seam, unitils

I'm calling `Component.getInstance(Needed.class)` in the constructor of one of my classes, which is not a seam component.
That works just fine, but I'm trying to cover it with unit tests and what I'm getting is `IllegalStateException` on the above line.
Is there a way to cover Component.getInstance with tests?

By the way I'm using unitils library...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [Service Locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) in your classes, which is not suited well for unit testing. Try moving to the [Dependency Injection pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This makes unit testing much easer.

Service Locator example:

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    private Needed dependency;

    public MyService()
    {
        this.dependency = 
            Component.getInstance(Needed.class);
    }
}
```

Dependency injection example:

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    private Needed dependency;

    public MyService(Needed dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

When doing dependency injection, your class won't have any reference to the container (`Component` in your case), which makes it much easier to unit test the class.